# How pass data from feeder into Kafka message?

Tags: java, gatling

I am trying to scenario when data is taken from feed and passed to Kafka topic with usage of Gatling and existing plugging for Kafka.

```
    public static ScenarioBuilder kafkaScenario() {
        FeederBuilder.FileBased<Object> random = CoreDsl.jsonFile("requests.json").random();
        return CoreDsl.scenario("A")
                .feed(random)
                .exec(kafka("kafka request")
                        .send("test", "#{host}"));
    }

    
    
    public static ScenarioBuilder httpScenario() {
        FeederBuilder.FileBased<Object> random = CoreDsl.jsonFile("requests.json").random();
        return CoreDsl.scenario("B")
                .feed(random)
                .exec(http("http request")
                        .get("/register?host=#{host}")
                        .check(jmesPath("id").saveAs("usernameRsp")))
                .exec(session -> {
                    System.out.println("response: " + session.get("patientIdRsp"));
                    return session;
                });
    }
```

In order to access value from feed I use `${host}` but on consumer side it just receives `${host}` as message instead of expected values `top1`, `top2` or `top3`.

The output in first exec shows different values of `host`.

**UPD:**
I've tried to make same with `http` so it works well and `host` value is passed from the file.

**UPD 2:**
The `send` method implementation uses inside `toStaticValueExpression` what makes it not working properly, when changing it to `toStringExpression` it works well for a case describe above.

What's wrong in this code for Kafka scenario? Thanks!

Comment: As the creator of my own Kafka plugin, I suggest giving it a try - https://github.com/Amerousful/gatling-kafka. There, everything must be OK)

Comment: @Amerousful does it work only on scala?

Comment: Currently yes, but a new release with Java support is on the way.

Comment: I released version 2.0 which supports Java https://github.com/Amerousful/gatling-kafka/releases/tag/2.0

Comment: Awesome @Amerousful! Looking into it